# React Native: Unrecognized font family 'Font Name' to pick default font

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

This is a pretty generic error but in my case the difference is I installed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker package and implementing it by first importing:

```
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
```

Then I'm creating the DopDownPicke as:

```
            <DropDownPicker items={[
                { label: '1', value: 1 },
                { label: '2', value: 2 },
                { label: '3', value: 3 },
                { label: '4', value: 4 },
                { label: '5', value: 5 },
            ]} defaultValue={this.state.noOfIndToVac}
                style={styles.dropDown}
                itemStyle={{
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                }} dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
                onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
                    noOfIndToVac: item.value
                })} />
```

This is when I get the error

> Unrecognized font family 'Feather'

I honestly don't care if I have the Feather font or not in the app, so is it possible to add a line of code that picks the system default font and stops showing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't finished setting up react native vector icons, because if you are successful, the feather icon should be included, check this official repository https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite Feather font with whichever is the default font? I know `DropDownPicker` depends on this, but just wondering as I want to use less third-party packages as possible.